# get historical languages data from GitHub API

Tags: github, github-api

I want to make a timeline for the usage of different languages in my private repositories. The GitHub API provides the bytes of data in each language with `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/languages`
as well as the meta data on each commit with `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/commits/:sha` which doesn't have a 'languages' attribute.

The brute-force idea is to clone my repositories and measure it myself at each commit from the history of commits. But I was wondering if there is a smarter way to do so.